# How to dedent Python new line with shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

(**some people were telling me such shortcut does not exist universally, just want to verify that)

I was following this python tutorial online, and the guy get a new line directly with one level dedent

for example if i have: (.... represent spaced indent)

```
....if i == 0:
........continue
```

after press enter i would get a new line with indent like this still in the if statement:

```
....if i == 0: 
........continue
........
```

However this guy seems to use some shortcut and get an indent that jumps out of the if statement directly like this:

```
....if i == 0: 
........continue
....
```

so he doesnt need to press backspace four times to delete the space

Help, I have been coding for years, never heard of this shortcut and would love to find out.
I have been trying different combos for half an hour and havent found it

I don't think this is some special shortcut to the script editor in this case (this is rhino grasshopper internal python script editor, extremely simple, basically has not shortcut for anything)

Here's the video I was referring to

[Updated GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJtnX.gif)

Edit: this editor barely has any internal shortcuts, like 90% of the sublime shortcuts, not even auto comment. So I am wondering if there is some new line dedent shortcut out there (not TAB + SHIFT)

Comment: It really sounds like your question is really about the Grasshopper editor.  As such 1) it's not a good fit for SO (it isn't a "programming question"), and 2) it begs the question as to why you don't just switch editors?  I'd recommend trying VS Code; you mentioned Sublime; there are many, many other choices.  See also: https://discourse.mcneel.com/t/grasshopper-python-editor-even-a-bigger-mess-in-the-latest-wip/81051.  Voting to close :(

Comment: @FoggyDay so basically no such universal shortcut exist? That's basically the whole question. But if anyone knows, please let me know

Comment: There is no universal shortcut. PyCharm unindents when you press Backspace once in this context, but this is specific to PyCharm, not a general rule.